# JavaFX - Customizing TextField

Tags: css, javafx

When I type inside one of JavaFX's TextFields, the text doesn't go all the way from one side to the other, it sort of cuts off early. I guess there is some sort of padding inside the TextField that prevents the text from taking up the whole space. How can I make this go away? I tried CSS but I couldn't find any attributes to change this.

The reason I need this fixed is I am writing a program where the user types in their initials, and they put one initial in each TextField. The problem is that in order for a single letter to be visible the TextField has to be about 30 pixels wide at least, and it looks too bulky and annoying at that size.

How can I get rid of this padding? If I can't then what are some possible alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textfield.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0.333333em 0 0.333333em 0;");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please tell me where you found this? Because its not in the JavaFX CSS documentation, and I would like to know what else I'm missing.

Comment: Found it. Ctrl + F on the reference webpage revealed it to be listed under Region/Other. Tricky to find.